# What are the default Profile Locations/Paths for Documents, Pictures, Music for Spanish, French and English?

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-xp, profiles

I am dealing with a program that can reads in a file that uses absolute paths rather than relative paths.  Problem is, this can be French, English and Spanish.  What I'm looking for is a definition of what the user profile directory is set up like in English, Spanish and French.

For Instance, English is relatively east and documented:
XP:
c:\Documents and Settings\user\my documents
c:\Documents and Settings\user\my documents\my pictures
and so on

Win7/8:
c:\users\user\pictures
c:\users\user\music
c:\users\user\documents
and so on

However, for Spanish I can't find documentation, for instance, I think it is
XP:
c:\configuraciones y documentos\user\mis documentos
c:\configuraciones y documentos\user\mis documentos\mis imagenes
c:\configuraciones y documentos\user\mis documentos\mis imágenes
c:\configuraciones y documentos\user\mis documentos\mis fotos

7/8:
c:\users\user\documentos
c:\users\user\fotos
c:\users\user\imagenes
c:\users\user\imágenes

95/98/ME/NT/2000/etc - did they even have standard locations for music, documents and pictures anywhere????

Roughly, I see these all over google and bing but nothing that seems like a firm "this is what it is" and I see virtually nothing on French.  I've searched MSDN, but only see anything on English.

Anyway, what i'm doing it doing a replace on part of a pathname that I'm reading in these files, but, I can't replace unless I know what the paths are supposed to be.

Comment: If somebody is giving you a list of paths, then just use the paths provided; don't second-guess them. if you are generating a list of paths, and you want them to be migratable, then don't generate absolute paths. Use CSIDL-relative paths. That way they will adapt the user's language.

Answer (score 1):

well, the best I can come up with, though I can find no real documentation on it.

English:
Windows 95:
C:\My Documents

Windows 98, Windows ME:
C:\My Documents
C:\My Pictures
C:\My Music

Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows 2003:
Unknown

Windows XP, Vista:
C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents
C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Pictures
C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\My Music

Windows 7/8
c:\users\username\My Documents
c:\users\username\My Music
c:\users\username\My Pictures

Spanish:
Windows 95:
C:\Mis Documentos

Windows 98, Windows ME:
C:\Mis Documentos
C:\Mis Imagenes or C:\Mis Imágenes
C:\Mi Musica

Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows 2003:
Unknown

Windows XP, Vista:
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Mis Documentos
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Mis Documentos\Mis Imagenes or C:\Documents and Settings\username\Mis Documentos\Mis Imágenes
C:\Documents and Settings\username\Mis Documentos\Mi Musica

Or it could be C:\documentos y configuraciones or c:\configuraciones y documentos

Windows 7/8
c:\users\username\Mis Documentos
c:\users\username\Mi Musica
c:\users\username\Mis Imágenes or c:\users\username\Mis Imagenes

or it could be c:\usuarios\users....

French:
Unknown at this time